# Need a good MS Access 2003 reference

Tags: ms-access, vba, reference

I am forced to use old Microsoft 2003 VBA.
Unfortunatelly the MS reference is hardly usable (in my eyes: more than bad) I wonder if anybody has ever uses this.
So my question is: is there any place in the web which offers s.th. like a usable reference?
At MS I did not found anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You astonish me.

**VBA**

[Microsoft Access Visual Basic Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296748(v=office.11).aspx)

**Jet**

[Jet Database Engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc805477.aspx)
[Microsoft Jet SQL Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/CH006252688.aspx)

**Jet SQL**

[Microsoft Jet SQL Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/CH006252688.aspx)
[Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

**Design and Development**

[Fundamentals of Relational Database Design, Paul Litwin, 2003](http://r937.com/relational.html)
[Access cookbook](http://books.google.ie/books/about/Access_cookbook.html?id=qtgInMAAA0oC&redir_esc=y)
[Location of the Northwind sample files in Access 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824265)

**Access MVPs**

[Access MVPs](http://access.mvps.org/access/)
[Access MVPs Websites](http://www.mvps.org/links.html#Access)

**Stackoverflow**

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+tutorial

Comment: Yes there are some references in the net. Most of them I already found. Lets give a positive example: In Java every class is documented with all methods and properties. All classes are linked. Try to find a simple overview of all functions in the MS reference, e.g. String functions like "left()".

Comment: I should have written it first: Thank you for the list. I will have a close look into the links "Access MVPs".

Comment: The thing is, you are looking for a reference set that is two releases and 9 years out of date. In Access, the F1 key and the object browser were always very helpful and you can, for the most part, use the 2010 refernces, you just have to be a little careful. Here is another link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841339.aspx